# Outputting relevant input/output to a GUI, having received input in the console

Tags: java

I need to display some relevant information (like an introduction, yes/no questions and other questions) to a user via a gui, who then enters their response into the console.  However, I cannot for the life of me think of or find a way to do this.  How can I run the GUI but still allow input into the console?  Here is some cut down code I have that shows what I'm trying to do. I'm doing this from a pps frame class that handles the container stuff. I just need to add buttons, text fields and later on action events.

```
public class gui extends XFrame
{
    private JTextField[] textFieldsUneditable;

        public gui()
        {
            super();
            textFieldsUneditable = new JTextField[10];
            for(int i=0; i<textFieldsUneditable.length; i++)
            {
                textFieldsUneditable[i] = new JTextField(42);
                textFieldsUneditable[i].setEditable(false);
                add(textFieldsUneditable[i]);
            }

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // code code code
        }
```

But what I have is other methods, of which I want to run and then output into these uneditable JTextFields using setText in the GUI after the user has responded in the console. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Why not use a GUI to input the values also?

Comment: i'm required to do it in stages and this is one of the stages.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (example below):

1. Create a GUI and and save the references to the fields you want to update
2. Get the console input line-by-line, possible using a `Scanner`.
3. Find the field you want to update
4. Update it using a thread safe way using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` or `invokeLater`
5. *Repeat 3 and 4 till you are done.*

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // create a new frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    // create some fields that you can update from the console
    JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        frame.add(fields[i] = new JTextField("" + i)); // add them to the frame

    // show the frame (it will pop up and you can interact with in - spawns a thread)
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Create a scanner so that you can get some input from the console (the easy way)
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

        // get the field you want to update
        final JTextField field = fields[i];

        // get the input from the console
        final String line = s.nextLine();

        // update the field (must be done thread-safe, therefore this construct)
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() { field.setText(line); }
        });
    }
}
```